# Ошибка "cannot resolve symbol" в intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, spring-boot, sdk

Подскажите пожалуйста, может кто сталкивался. При загрузке любого проекта из github, в  IDEA, постоянно возникает "cannot resolve symbol". Через maven проект собирается. Если через консоль запускать проект командой spring-boot:run, то все работает отлично, но в IDEA все горит красным.

Пробовал делать реимпорт, в ProjectStructure установил SDK, все равно горит красным. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите пример методов, которые подчёркивает

Comment: Что-то не импортируется. Без конкретных примеров не скажешь, что именно.

Comment: Если в поле класса набрать Map, в списке для импорта появляется java.util.Map? (подсказка идеи)

Comment: @Bakhuss Да появляется

Comment: Вы импортируете `pom.xml`? Что показывает во вкладке "Maven Projects" есть зависимости или какая-то ошибка?